# Editing the hba_file using postgresql in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have installed postgresql as a database in my rails app. I am having trouble configuring the database. I followed stack overflow posts and figured out how to create a user and create databases. The problem is authenticating the user. I know that involves configuring the `hba_file;`

I ran the following command to open the config file.

```
sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

I know I have to edit the following line in the `hba_file`. I need to change `peer to md5.`

**# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket**

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

I have found the file but I am having a lot of trouble editing the file. I press `I` to insert/edit new values. I don't know how to save the file. I closed the terminal and opened the file again. I get the following error.

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/.pg_hba.conf.swp"
          owned by: root   dated: Wed Apr 13 01:26:42 2016
         file name: /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
          modified: YES
         user name: root   host name: kpauls-scorecliq-2942283
        process ID: 32423
While opening file "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf"
             dated: Wed Mar 16 04:06:59 2016

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/.pg_hba.conf.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/.pg_hba.conf.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

I am not sure how to edit the `hba_file` file and save the changes. I understand how to create users and creating databases. However, I am having a very hard time editing the file. I am not sure how to edit and save the file. I read several posts on stack regarding this topic but they don't really explain how to edit the file. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: your problem is with `vi`, not with postgres.

Comment: I use that so I can open that with vim. Is there another way to open that file. I am using cloud9 as my platform for development.

Comment: To edit a file you'll need an editor. And you need to know how to operate it. If `vi` is confusing you, you could try another editor, such as nano.

Comment: @wildplasser, cloud 9 offers the following editors. Default, Vim, Emacs and sublime. I don't think i can use nano because that's not one of the editors. I have used sublime before. Any idea how I would use sublime to open the file. Would I just type in sudo sublime /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

Comment: Well: give it a try! BTW: you can exit ci by `:wq` +return (:=write file and quit) quitting without saving would be `:q!` Uou enter insert mode by `i`, and finish it with ESC. #vicrashcourse

Comment: @wildplasser, I just did. A few different combinations. The combination   sudo su /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf gives me the following message
No passwd entry for user '/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf'

Comment: `sudo su /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` is nonsense.

Comment: @wildplasser, I actually pulled up the documentation for vim and how to edit it. You mentioned it as well. However, when I open the file I still get the message mentioned above.

Comment: Because you didn't finish your first `vi` editing session. The editor is still running in it's terminal window (or you killed it). Either finish it properly, or kill it. (and remove the .swp file)

Comment: @wildplasser, I got it. I saved the changes in the editor and deleted the .swp file. I had never used vim before. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Thank you so much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

## USE NANO to edit the pg_hba.conf file.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

You need to find this kind of line

```
local   postgres   postgres   peer
```

and change that line into are as under

```
local   postgres   postgres   md5
```

than then just press `Ctrl+s` for save file

## restart postgresql

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
```